# Serialize & Deserialize Unity3D MonoBehaviour script

Tags: serialization, unity-game-engine

Background: Classes that inherit from Monobehaviour can't be serialized.

Premise: A way to save the data (variables/fields and their values) of a MonoBehaviour script so it can be serialized, and deserialize it again and use this data to "fill in" a corresponding MonoBehaviour script's variable/field values.

Tried so far:

1. Having a serializable "wrapper/container" class that has the same fields as the MB script, but does not inherit from MB. Works nicely but every MV script needs it's own wrapper class and it's own wrapping function.
2. Serializing a `List<FieldInfo>` and fill it with the MB's fields... Works 30%;

   - The `FieldInfos` get added but are of the wrong Type, and
   - When deserialzing their values can't be accessed because an instance of a class is needed, but only a list is available

I feel like it can't be that hard but my Reflection skills and related are limited but seeing as saving/loading is a rather common feature I hope there is either someone who did it or someone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to serialize a MonoBehaviour using a BinaryFormatter built in .NET. There are a few options you can consider:

1. Using a [Memento Patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). That is (more or less) what you have tried to achieve using a wrapper. Momento assumes a saving and restoring internal state of objects, so serialization is one of techniques.
2. Using Unity Serialization, by declaring the methods:

   void Serialize(){}

   void Deserialize(){}

   In your MonoBehaviour script, so within the methods you will choose the properties/fields you want to serialize/deserialize.
3. There is an interesting framework, source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/vexe/VFW). It has a custom serialization framework that lets you serialize almost anything (not only monobehaviors). I have never used it, [here is the forum page](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/free-vfw-1-3-full-set-of-drawers-serialize-interfaces-generics-auto-props-delegates.266165/) on Unity3d forum, I believe it's worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did look at some custom frameworks but I was hoping to avoid using one as they tend to be too far-reaching for my needs and thus, hard to reverse-engineer should I need to make changes :) They idea is to load and save gameObject when a saved game is saved/loaded, I have all I need like instantiating the right prefab, keeping track of children, and so on, but saving and loading the data from the components eludes me thus far :( I guess I'll have to go back to using wrappers, at least it gives a maximum of control. Any other ideas welcome of course! :)

Comment: Update: Got a promising new way of doing things. I copied this method from the UnitySerializer asset. I still have a generic wrapper class to store the data for a gameobject; it has values for the Transform variables, as well as the id of it and it's parent (if any). As for MB script components, the class had a Dictionary<string,object> where string holds the name of a field and the object holds the field's value.

Comment: Then, it's just a matter of going through a gameobject's component's fields and adding them to the dictionary, and upon deserializing, going through the KeyValuePairs of the deserialized dictionary and getting the fields using the string (name), and setting the corresponding value using the corresponding dictionary.

Comment: That's awesome! If it's not too big please share your code as it would be of great help for other users seeking for the same question

Comment: Yes, I plan to add an answer here once I got it fully tested. Yesterday I just quickly tested it with a short script with int type variables, today I want to expand it to see if it works with Unity-specific variables, or maybe if workarounds are needed.

Comment: So, I'm about an inch further towards my goal. The big problem are variables that are not serializable, namely Vector3. I can exclude those fields from being added to the dictionary by checking is they are marked as serializable, and add a seperate serializable wrapper variable to the script in question, like a Float3 which holds the Vector3's values.

Comment: This wrapper variable would get assigned by calling SendMessage("OnSerialization") for the gameobject that is being serialized, with the function taking the V3 values and putting them into the wrapper Float3 variable. It works but every script would need a custom tailored function of this type. If only I could access a non-serializable field's value...

Comment: Update: I have created a sample project that does basic GameObject serialization.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/serializehelper-free-save-and-load-utility-de-serialize-all-objects-in-your-scene.338148/

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is: ScriptableObject. That's what they're for.

Put your variables in a ScriptableObject and Unity will handle the serialisation and give you a custom editor and other nice features. Recommended.