# How to save objects via serialization, if they are monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to save my application state, so I did start creating the load and save functions for serialization.

Then I just hit a wall; when I realized that by default, any monobehaviour cannot be serialized.

So I told myself that I shall wrap the class then in a serializable object; but even in that case, I believe you can't have a monobehaviour object and mark it as serializable object.

Before jump from my sofa and end this life; I seriously hope that there is a way to avoid to copy ALL the elements in various classes (so far I have 16 classes, each one carry various object collections made of lists or dictionaries of other classes types), to actually save the state of my application.

It will take me forever to write a method that take every single value from every object of every class; while I was under the impression that saving each object, at least I could retrieve the data from the saved object and replace the current data on load.

Comment: Maybe you want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29720295/5311735

Comment: Thanks, I did take some hints from that thread; although there is not a straightforward answer, about how to avoid to re-write part of your code to account for the fact that some classes can't be serializable. It was a good reading to at least getting started. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to saving complex data structures I always go for using protobuf.Net
[Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net) is a link to the NuGet package. I also suggest that you follow [this](http://purdyjotut.blogspot.bg/2013/10/using-protobuf-in-unity3d.html) tutorial for a more in-depth look. The tutorial is really detailed and it explains how to create everything you need to store your data. I've used this multiple times and can guarantee that it is platform independent. And I'm sure you can create a ProtoContract on a MonoBehaviour. You will just have to recreate your class structure in the ProtoBuf project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I did read the tutorial and it is straightforward; but the amount of work needed is still quite a lot, compared to just go on with a memento pattern. I would not like to risk to spend time implementing this, and then figure out that what I want to serialize won't work as expected. I already spent 2 months with this issue almost; and the clock is ticking :) thanks for the suggestion though!