# How to save game settings into file in Unity games without returning serialization error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building an Android game and the Options menu provides 3 different settings: background music volume, sound effects volume, and screen side placement of the shooting button. There is also the high score which should be saved.

I tried creating a script building on an answer someone provided, but when I test it with the music volume slider it keeps returning errors about things not being serializable. At first it said "SerializationException: Type 'GameData' in Assembly 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable", so I tried adding "[System.Serializable]" above the class code as suggested somewhere, but now instead it returns the error "SerializationException: Type 'UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour' in Assembly 'UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable".

Also, after the serialization error it also writes the error "IOException: Sharing violation on path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\LocalLow\CompanyName\AppName\save.dat".

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

[System.Serializable]
public class GameData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int highScore = 0;
    public float musicVol = 1;
    public float sfxVol = 1;
    public int shootSide = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        LoadFile();
    }
    public void HighScoreValue(int highS)
    {
        highScore = highS;
        SaveData();
    }
    public void MusicValue(float musicV)
    {
        musicVol = musicV;
        SaveData();
    }
    public void SfxValue(float sfxV)
    {
        sfxVol = sfxV;
        SaveData();
    }
    public void ShootSideValue(int shootS)
    {
        shootSide = shootS;
        SaveData();
    }
    private void SaveData()
    {
        string destination = Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.dat";
        FileStream file;

        if (File.Exists(destination))
        {
            file = File.OpenWrite(destination);
        }
        else
        {
            file = File.Create(destination);
        }
        GameData data = gameObject.AddComponent<GameData>();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
    private void LoadFile()
    {
        string destination = Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.dat";
        FileStream file;

        if (File.Exists(destination))
        {
            file = File.OpenRead(destination);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("File not found");
            return;
        }
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        GameData data = (GameData)formatter.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
        highScore = data.highScore;
        musicVol = data.musicVol;
        sfxVol = data.sfxVol;
        shootSide = data.shootSide;
    }
}
```

What is wrong in the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MonoBehaviour` may not be instantiated using the `new` keyword which is kind of required for the deserializer. Your additional `AddComponent` and `GetComponent` are not required, since this script already **is** the component you want to use on a `GameObject`.

---

You should (at least I would) separate the serializable type into only a pure data-class/-struct and use an instance of it in the MonoBehaviour which implements logic.

Could look like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class GameDataContainer
{
    public int highScore = 0;
    public float musicVol = 1;
    public float sfxVol = 1;
    public int shootSide = 1;
}

public class GameData : MonoBehaviour
{
    // since this is a serialized, 
    // it will be initialized with a valid instance by default
    public GameDataContainer data;

    // NEVER use +"/" for system paths!
    // initilaize this only once
    private string destination => Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "save.dat");

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        LoadFile();
    }

    public void HighScoreValue(int highS)
    {
        data.highScore = highS;
        SaveData();
    }

    public void MusicValue(float musicV)
    {
        data.musicVol = musicV;
        SaveData();
    }

    public void SfxValue(float sfxV)
    {
        data.sfxVol = sfxV;
        SaveData();
    }

    public void ShootSideValue(int shootS)
    {
        data.shootSide = shootS;
        SaveData();
    }

    private void SaveData()
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(file, data);
        }
    }

    private void LoadFile()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(destination))
        {
            Debug.Log("File not found");
            return;
        }

        using(var file = File.Open(destination, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            data = (GameDataContainer)formatter.Deserialize(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually someone already suggested on the Unity forum to separate this into a data-class and a handler class, which I think works now without further change (even with the "/" so I'm not sure why it matters), but you offered a couple of further adjustments that could make it work better.

Comment: the `+ "/"` is extremly dangerous if you work with Unity and possibly build to different target platforms using different OS (e.g. / on Unix vs \ or :\ for a drive path on Windows) ... [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) simply inserts the correct path separator according to the OS your code is running on

Comment: Thanks! Good to know.

Comment: Although it seems you can't use the persistentDataPath from the MonoBehaviour constructor, it tells me to put it in Start or Awake (and then also it needs to not be readonly). **EDIT:** It also seems it doesn't add any slash when using your method. It saved the file as "Appnamesave.dat" within the company folder instead of CompanyName/AppName/save.dat

Comment: Oops, my mistake about the slash missing part. I kept the + and wrote it only in the first field instead of using a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `GameData` class inherits from Unity's `MonoBehaviour`, serialization would require `MonoBehaviour` to also be serializable; which it appears it is not.

Perhaps this will help: [Serialize & Deserialize Unity3D MonoBehaviour script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719869/serialize-deserialize-unity3d-monobehaviour-script)

Comment: It seems both the Start method and the ability to drag the Unity game object to which the script is attached into UI buttons' fields requires MonoBehaviour. I will take a look at the link you provided.